# single active button in ngFor angular

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I have a query regarding active button in angular. Scenario is: Amongst a list of applications, if a user selects one application and click Open Channel, then rest others should be deactivated. Please look into my HTML

```
   <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let a of apps">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>

      <mat-panel-title>
        {{a.name}}
      </mat-panel-title>

      <mat-panel-description>
        {{a.info}}
      </mat-panel-description>

      <mat-panel-description>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="clickedConnect(a.name, a._id)">Open Channel</button>

      </mat-panel-description>

      <mat-panel-description>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="clickedDisconnect(a._id)">Close Channel</button>
      </mat-panel-description>

      <mat-panel-description>
        <mat-chip-list>

          <mat-chip *ngIf="isAppActive(a._id)==true" style="background: green;" selected>Openned</mat-chip>
          <mat-chip *ngIf="isAppActive(a._id)==false" style="background: red;" selected>Closed</mat-chip>

        </mat-chip-list>**strong text**
      </mat-panel-description>

    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

  </mat-expansion-panel>
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Is this not working? Please try to follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to create better questions :)

Answer (score 0):

1. create a variable named **selectedId**
2. **On button click of open channel, assign the clicked application id to selectedId**.
3. Make the **selectedId as null when you want to enable all applications.**

> ```
> <ng-container *ngFor="let a of apps">
> <mat-expansion-panel [disabled]="selectedId && a._id != selectedId ">
> // rest of the content
> </mat-expansion-panel>
> </ng-container>
> ```

Hope this is what you asked for.